# Batik 1.14 error when trying to rasterize SVG file

Tags: java, batik

In Windows 10 x64 with Java 8.281, I have downloaded BATIK 1.14 binaries from:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/download.html

In a Windows command prompt, I tried to rasterize one of the included SVG files, but it did not work:

> C:\COMP_CLI_Tools\batik-bin-1.14\batik-1.14>java -jar
> batik-rasterizer-1.14.jar samples\textRotateShadows.svg About to
> transcode 1 SVG file(s)
>
> Converting textRotateShadows.svg to samples\textRotateShadows.png ...
> org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null Enclosed
> Exception: Unable to transform src image
> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTranscoder.java:132)
> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:158)
> at org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverter.transcode(SVGConverter.java:1008)
> at org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverter.execute(SVGConverter.java:719)
> at org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.Main.execute(Main.java:954)
> at org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.Main.main(Main.java:1007) Caused by: java.awt.image.ImagingOpException: Unable to transform src
> image
> at java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp.filter(AffineTransformOp.java:358)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AffineRed.genRect(AffineRed.java:193)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AffineRed.copyData(AffineRed.java:109)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.Any2sRGBRed.copyData(Any2sRGBRed.java:166)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractRed.getData(AbstractRed.java:523)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:264)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:455)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:550)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.genRect(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:141)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.copyData(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:117)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.Any2LsRGBRed.copyData(Any2LsRGBRed.java:109)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.GaussianBlurRed8Bit.copyData(GaussianBlurRed8Bit.java:232)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractRed.getData(AbstractRed.java:523)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AffineRed.genRect(AffineRed.java:146)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AffineRed.copyData(AffineRed.java:109)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.Any2sRGBRed.copyData(Any2sRGBRed.java:166)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:347)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:455)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:550)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CanvasGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CanvasGraphicsNode.java:159)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.genRect(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:141)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.copyData(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:117)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.TileCacheRed.genRect(TileCacheRed.java:63)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractTiledRed.drawBlockInPlace(AbstractTiledRed.java:625)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractTiledRed.drawBlock(AbstractTiledRed.java:544)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractTiledRed.copyToRasterByBlocks(AbstractTiledRed.java:430)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractTiledRed.copyData(AbstractTiledRed.java:297)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.TranslateRed.copyData(TranslateRed.java:105)
> at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.renderer.StaticRenderer.repaint(StaticRenderer.java:393)
> at org.apache.batik.gvt.renderer.StaticRenderer.repaint(StaticRenderer.java:343)
> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTranscoder.java:111)
> ... 6 more ... error (SVGConverter.error.while.rasterizing.file)

Comment: Why do you need the library? SVG can be rasterized in many ways. Also, does exception depend on a file?

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this library.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the exact same problem (with a few of the batik sample SVGs). Batik 1.14, Java 8. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a [discussion here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/453) that sheds some more light on this.

**Workaround 1 - use "one param" stdDeviation in the SVG's feGaussianBlur.**

The specific SVG element that causes this error is the [stdDeviation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stdDeviation) property of [feGaussianBlur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur). If two params are provided, it does not work:

```
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2 3" /> <!-- DOESN'T WORK -->
```

However, if only one param is specified, it works fine:

```
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" /> <!-- WORKS! -->
```

The "two param" version allows different blur to be applied on x and y axes. The "one param" version applies the same blur amount to both x and y.

**Workaround 2 - Upgrade to Java 9 or higher.**

It seems to be a bug with Java 1.7 (and 1.8 in my experience - and possibly others). I can confirm that it is resolved in Java 9 (9.0.4 - Windows).